# Can't use GTK Inspector for gnome-terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal, gtk3, gtkinspector

I am trying to inspect the `gnome-terminal` with the GTK Inspector. This inspector works on other GTK programs like `gnome-calculator` and `gedit`. However, when I try to run this on the `gnome-terminal`, nothing happens. I've tried the many possibilities like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (which never works for me) and running `GTK_DEBUG=interactive gnome-terminal`. The latter works for other GTK programs but not for the terminal. It also doesn't matter if I run this command from a different terminal like `xterm`. Any suggestions on how I can GTK Inspect the `gnome-terminal`?

Comment: I wonder if the issue is that gnome-terminal now uses a client-server architecture - so that the command `gnome-terminal` only actually loads the application if there are no extant gnome-terminals. Did you try closing all gnome-terminals first, or using the `--disable-factory` option (if your version still supports it)? See [Debugging GNOME Terminal - Running a separate instance](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Terminal/Debugging) and [Run true multiple process instances of gnome-terminal](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/201900/run-true-multiple-process-instances-of-gnome-terminal)

Comment: I killed all my Gnome Terminals and ran the command `GTK_DEBUG=interactive gnome-terminal` from `xterm`. Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 12):

I've found the solution, I'm using GTK+ 3.22 for reference, just need to turn on this setting:

```
gsettings set org.gtk.Settings.Debug enable-inspector-keybinding true
```

And then the "Help" menu of gnome-terminal will show a "Inspector" item you just need to click it.

*This is for the VTE widget only:*
Alternatively, if you are using jhbuild, the vte module has a test program for the vte widget (that gnome-terminal uses) so you can run it like this:

```
# inside jhbuild/checkout/vte
GTK_DEBUG=interactive src/testvte
```

**Update:**

On **20.04**, the "Inspector" link is in the gnome-terminal window's "hamburger‑menu‑button > Advanced" submenu.

Comment: Wow, that was well hidden!

Comment: The org.gtk.Settings.Debug schema is part of libgtk-3-dev.  You need to install that package or you'll get a "no such schema" error.

Answer (score 0):

You can recompile gnome-terminal with `--enable-debug` passed to the `./configure` step, and then it'll have a Help -> Inspector menu entry which works properly.

(I'm not sure how to inspect gnome-terminal as it is shipped by Ubuntu, or whether it is possible at all.)